# How to set semi transparent background of HTML form with images in text fields

Tags: php, html, css

Hi I want to create a simple `HTML` form with a `semi transparent background` also I want to set an image on the left in text field(input field).

Here is the example where I saw that form:

[Demo Of my requirement](http://www.login2yatra.com?source=stov)

In this form there is icon on the left hand side in each input type and also the form is `semi transparent.`

Is there any way to do so either by `css` or `html` ?

please Help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use opacity, Background-color and Background-image property. Try something and come here if you face any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with CSS

```
<div class="form-container">
<form>
<input type="text" name="" value="">
</form>
</div>
```

Css File :

```
input {
    background-image:url('mon-image.png');
}

.form-container{
     background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8); 
}
```

You can also create a white semi transparent PNG file of 32x32 px and use it as background image and repeat it on X and Y

```
.form-container{
     background-image:url('my-transparent-png.png');
     background-repeat:  repeat ; 
}
```

This last method works with most of web browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS you can do:

```
background-color: rbga(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
```

You can read more about it at [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `opacity` for these images to look `semi transparent` via `CSS`

**Example**

```
img
{
 opacity:.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way with CSS would be

```
opacity: 0.5;
```